# For what values of $a>0$ is the equation $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(n-0.5)^2+a} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a}}$ true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

For what values of $a>0$ is the equation $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(n-0.5)^2+a} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a}}$$ true?

I saw this claim [here](https://vixra.org/pdf/2004.0056v1.pdf), and know it's not true for all $a$ since the LHS converges while the RHS diverges as $a \to 0.$ However, as $a$ increases we seem to get a better and better approximation.

This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1323295) provides the helpful formula $$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+\alpha)^2+\gamma^2} = \frac{\pi}{\gamma} \frac{\sinh{2\gamma \pi}}{\cosh{2\gamma \pi}-\cos{2\alpha \pi}}.$$ Unfortunately, $a$ may not be an integer, so we can't just plug in $\alpha = -0.5, \gamma = a$ and hope to fold the sums over negative and positive integers over each other. Any other ideas?

Comment: $(-n-0.5)^2=(n+0.5)^2=((n-1)-0.5)^2$ so you basically get the same sum.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Is it possible to extend this to rational $a$, or even just the rationals in $(0,1)$? Then we can transfer to the complex plane, prove the sum converges uniformly on compact sets, deduce it represents an entire function, and conclude that the sum is $\pi \tanh(\sqrt{a} \pi)/\sqrt{a}$ for all $a$ by the identity principle.

Comment: You're right, the ability to transfer between sums from $-\infty \to \infty$ and sums from $1 \to \infty$ depended on $\alpha,$ not $\gamma$ in the formula. I wasn't careful enough before dismissing the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start from the result linked in the question:
$$
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+\alpha)^2+\gamma^2} = \frac{\pi}{\gamma} \frac{\sinh{2\gamma \pi}}{\cosh{2\gamma \pi}-\cos{2\alpha \pi}}.
$$
For the specific case of $\alpha = -\frac{1}{2}$, it is not too hard to see that
$$
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{(n-\frac12)^2+\gamma^2} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-\frac12)^2+\gamma^2},
$$
and so we have
$$
2 \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-\frac12)^2+\gamma^2} = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-\frac12)^2+\gamma^2} \\=\frac{\pi}{\gamma} \frac{\sinh{2\gamma \pi}}{\cosh{2\gamma \pi}-\cos{ \pi}} = \frac{\pi}{\gamma} \frac{\sinh{2\gamma \pi}}{\cosh{2\gamma \pi}+ 1}.
$$
But $\sinh 2x = 2 \sinh x \cosh x$ and $\cosh 2x + 1 = 2 \cosh^2 x$, so
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(n-\frac12)^2+\gamma^2} = \frac{\pi}{\gamma} \tanh{\gamma \pi} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a}} \tanh\left(\sqrt{a} \pi\right),
$$
where we have identified $\gamma = \sqrt{a}$ in the last step.  As the OP notes, this should have a finite limit as $a \to 0$, and a bit of work shows that this limit is indeed finite and equal to $\pi^2$.

Thus, the given formula is true for all values of $a$ for which $\tanh(\sqrt{a} \pi) = 1$, which is...  none of them.  For all real $x$, $-1< \tanh(x) < 1$.  However, the hyperbolic tangent function does asymptotically approach 1;  in fact, asymptotically we have
$$
\tanh(\sqrt{a} \pi) \approx 1 - 2 e^{- 2\sqrt{a} \pi}.
$$
Even for $a = 1$, we have $\tanh(\pi) \approx 0.996...$ and so the result holds to within less than 1%.  It is not too hard to envision an amateur numerologist stumbling upon this relation "experimentally" with a computer and thinking that it must be true. (I note that the given equation was posted on viXra, which does have a reputation for such things.)  It is a remarkably good approximation, particularly for large values of $a$, but it is not in fact true.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the partial sum
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p \frac{2}{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+a}=\sum_{n=1}^p \frac{2}{ \left(n+\frac{1}{2} \left(-2 \sqrt{-a}-1\right)\right) \left(n+\frac{1}{2} \left(2
   \sqrt{-a}-1\right)\right)}$$ Use partial fraction decomposition and get
$$S_p=\frac{\psi \left(p-\sqrt{-a}+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi
  \left(p+\sqrt{-a}+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi
   \left(\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{-a}\right)+\psi
  \left(\sqrt{-a}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{-a}}$$ Now, using the asymptotics
$$\psi(n)=\log (n)-\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{12 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ Using it twice and continuing with Taylor series
$$S_p=\frac{\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{-a}\right)-\psi
   \left(\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{-a}\right)}{\sqrt{-a}}-\frac 2 p+\frac{4 a+1}{6 p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^5}\right)$$ and using now
$$\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}+b\right)-\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}-b\right)=\pi  \tan (\pi  b)$$ thus
$$\frac{\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{-a}\right)-\psi
   \left(\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{-a}\right)}{\sqrt{-a}}=\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{a}} \tanh \left(\pi  \sqrt{a}\right)$$ This is what Wolfram Alpha  provided.